# Babel error when working with npm workspace - plugin babel) SyntaxError: xxx.ts: Missing semicolon. (x:x)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, babeljs, npm-workspaces

Inside a file of an npm **workspace-a**, when I import a React Component located in a npm **workspace-b** I am getting the error: `plugin babel) SyntaxError: xxx.ts: Missing semicolon. (x:x)`

```
import MyComponentLocatedInWorspaceB from ‘../../anotherPackageWorkspace/direct/import’;
```

On dev time (eg: Running storybook) the relative/absolute import work fine, but when I create the `npm run build` then I get the error.

If I "disable" the "npm workspaces" the build works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't use relative/absolute import from one workspace into another.

So this is **wrong**:

```
import MyComponentLocatedInWorspaceB from ‘../../anotherPackageWorkspace/direct/import’;
```

The **correct** way of importing is

```
import MyComponentLocatedInWorspaceB from ‘@myDomain/workspaceB’;
```

Also, be sure to add/install **workspaceB** as a dependency of **workspaceA** in your *package.json*

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    ...
        "@myDomain/workspaceB": "^0.0.1"
    }
}
```

The dependency version number needs to coincide with the one in workspaceB owns *package.json*

PS: The Babel syntax error is completely misleading and doesn't help at all.